# How to umount a script

Tags: shell-script, backup, unmounting

Cron periodically has root run a script to backup certain partitions to an external USB drive. The script first removes the oldest backup, then backs up specific partitions and finally writes the result to a backup log file.

I want the drive to unmount when the removal, backup and print finish their work. I had no problem for many years simply with a final line: umount /mnt/backup.

But more recently the umount fails. I understand that I cannot safely do a lazy umount
and it seems that option is deprecated. I've tried prefacing the umount command with lines like sleep 10 and cd /. What final lines in the script will cleanly unmount the device for me?

Comment: Does the `umount` fail with any particular error message?

Comment: Before `umount` you can try `sync;sync;sync`